# How to wire multiple fxml controllers using spring dependency-injection?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, javafx

I read few spring tutorials with basic examples, and I am a bit confused on how to wire up things properly.

The trouble is, I wanted to use application context to pull singleton controller references, but I read on few other topics that application context should not be accessed directly unless it is absolutely necessary. I think I should use constructor to instantiate reference I want, but here things get all blurry for me.

I have javafx application with several fxml files. I have one main fxml and other are loaded dynamically inside main.

I'll use simplified code for example with two fxml controllers, **MainController.java** (for main fxml) and **ContentController.java** (for content fxml)

The idea is that content fxml has TabPane, and main fxml has button which opens new tab in TabPane on ContentController.

I am currently doing something like this

bean xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="contentController"
class="ContentController"
scope="singleton" />
</beans>
```

MainControler:

```
public class MainOverlayControler {

ApplicationContext context;

@FXML
private BorderPane borderPane;

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    loadContentHolder();
}
@FXML
private Button btn;

@FXML
private void btnOnAction(ActionEvent evt) {
    ((ContentController)context.getBean("contentController")).openNewContent();
}

private void loadContentHolder() {
    //set app context
    context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

    Node fxmlNode;
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    fxmlLoader.setController(context.getBean("contentController"));

    try {
    fxmlNode = (Node)fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Content.fxml").openStream());
    borderPane.setCenter(fxmlNode);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

ContentController:

```
public class ContentController {
@FXML
private TabPane tabPane;

public void openNewContent() {
    Tab newContentTab = new Tab();
    newContentTab.setText("NewTab");
    tabPane.getTabs().add(newContentTab);
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class MainFX extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("main.fxml").openStream());
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Question:**
I would like to know how to do same thing with constructor DI, or some other way if I misunderstood the concept.

I need to be able to call "openNewContent" on singleton instance of "ContentController" from multiple other controllers as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read some more on JavaFX and Spring integration. I recommend series by [Stephen Chin](http://javafx.steveonjava.com/javafx-and-spring-day-1/)

Basically, You need to embed your JavaFX classes into Spring context life cycle, and it is very nicely described in linked article.

You can also check his example project on [GitHub](https://github.com/steveonjava/JavaFX-Spring/), where the code is simplified with controller factories introduced in JavaFX 2.1 ([check here](https://github.com/steveonjava/JavaFX-Spring/commit/dd98a96f99c90c8ef18a7676ef5085bd921c3341))

Comment: Is this still state of the art? Or is there anything new in 2020?

Comment: @wilx IDK, I guess you did some googling for that. If not - here is one of the first results, I hope it will be useful https://spring.io/blog/2019/01/16/spring-tips-javafx