# Getting ComboBox value from another window TextField Control

Tags: java, javafx

I have two javaFx window. The first has a `ComboBox` and a `Button` to open second modal window.

In second window have a `TextField` and a `Button` `Control` to add the textField value to `MainController` Window's `ComboBox`. I am not getting any idea that how to do it. With a explained Example would great helpful for me. Below is the classes:

Main.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Contrller.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable{
    @FXML
    public ComboBox<String> combo;
    @FXML
    Button button;
    public ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList("A");
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        setCombo();

    }

    public void setCombo(){
        combo.setItems(list);
    }

    public void openModal() throws IOException {
        Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sec.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Send Mail");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root,800,600));
        primaryStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        //primaryStage.initOwner((Stage) menuBar.getScene().getWindow());
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

FXML for Main Window:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <children>
        <StackPane prefHeight="67.0" prefWidth="600.0">
            <children>
                <Label text="Get value from Another Child Dialog" />
            </children>
        </StackPane>
        <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
            <children>
                <Label text="Add Value of TextBox:" />
                <ComboBox fx:id="combo" prefWidth="150.0" />
            </children>
        </HBox>
        <Button fx:id="button" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openModal" text="Open Dialog" />
    </children>
</VBox>
```

Now Second window Sec.Java

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

/**
* Created by tracedot on 12/11/16.
*/
public class Sec implements Initializable{
    @FXML
    Button button;
    @FXML
    TextField textfield;
    public Controller controller=new Controller();

    public void setToCombo(){
        String cbvalue= textfield.getText();
        controller.combo.getItems().add(cbvalue);
        //controller.combo.itemsProperty().setValue(new ArrayList<String>().add());
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        //setToCombo();

    }
}
```

Second window FXML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<HBox alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Sec">
    <children>
        <TextField fx:id="textfield" />
        <Button fx:id="button" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setToCombo" text="Add to Combo" />
    </children>
</HBox>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40117925/javafx-many-static-fxml-controllers/40353976#40353976

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new instance of the `Controller` class also used for the main fxml won't help you communicate with the instance used with the fxml displayed. You have to pass the existing controller to the `Sec` instance used with the second fxml:

```
public class Sec implements Initializable{

    ...

    private Controller controller;

    public void setController(Controller controller ) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    ...

}
```

```
public void openModal() throws IOException {
    Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sec.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    primaryStage.setTitle("Send Mail");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root,800,600));
    primaryStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
    //primaryStage.initOwner((Stage) menuBar.getScene().getWindow());

    loader.<Sec>getController().setController(this);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

---

In case you want to close the new window after the input, you can also use `showAndWait()` to display the new stage:

```
public class Sec implements Initializable{

    ...
    private String result = null;

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setCombo() {
        result = textfield.getText();
        textField.getScene().getWindow().hide();
    }

    ...

}
```

```
public void openModal() throws IOException {
    Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sec.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    primaryStage.setTitle("Send Mail");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root,800,600));
    primaryStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
    //primaryStage.initOwner((Stage) menuBar.getScene().getWindow());

    primaryStage.showAndWait();

    String result = loader.<Sec>getController().getResult();

    if (result != null) {
        // if a result was selected, add it to the list
        list.add(result);
    }
}
```

Note that with this approach, if you want to reuse the second scene you also should add some functionality to reset the `result` field.

Comment: Seems a bit complicated as i am still new to java. But it works and i will study it to see how it is actually works.

Comment: If don't use the textField.getScene().getWindow().hide(); then it some times don't add some items.